# How to read the buffer from Paramiko channel completely?

Tags: python, ssh, buffer, paramiko

I am writing a Python script to SSH into my Raspberry Pi-Hole, and stream log data to a remote client. It reads out fine, but will stop before everything in the buffer arrives. I know this because the terminal I have opened right next to it running the same command will show more entries. If I continue to browse, those missing entries will arrive at the top of the stack of new data. Any ways to fix this? TIA - First Post :) -

```
import paramiko
from pathlib import Path
import time

def main():
    home = str(Path.home())
    command = 'pihole -t'

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys(home + '/.ssh/known_hosts')
    client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.101', username='pi')
    transport = client.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    channel.exec_command(command)
    while True:
        buffer = channel.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
        print(buffer)
        time.sleep(1)



    stdin.close()
    stdout.close()
    stderr.close()
    client.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Not sure how this applies, there is no error occurring it is just not printing out the entire output that a regular terminal would see until more data comes to push it from behind so to speak. I guess lowering or removing the buffer is what I'm after.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330517/18318581

Some minor modifications, calling the get_pty=True flag to request a psuedo-terminal, and calling the data from stdout.channel instead of just channel.recv. Fixed code below:

```
import paramiko
from pathlib import Path
import time

def main():
    home = str(Path.home())
    command = 'pihole -t'

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys(home + '/.ssh/known_hosts')
    client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.101', username='pi')
    transport = client.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    stdout, stdin, stderr = client.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)
    while True:
        # while channel.recv_ready():
            buffer = stdout.channel.recv(4096)
            print(buffer.decode('utf-8'))
            time.sleep(1)



    client.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: While I understand that my link didn't help, I do to think this is correct solution either. Faking terminal emulation support is wrong. Rather check if `pihole` does not have an option to prevent buffering when executed in a non-interactive environment.